# How to combine two code points to get one?

Tags: python, go, unicode, utf-8, utf

I know that unicode code point for `Á` is `U+00C1`. I read on internet and many forums and articles that I can also make an `Á` by combining characters `´` (unicode: `U+00B4`) and `A` (unicode: `U+0041`).

My question is simple. How to do it? I tried something like this. **I decided to try it in golang, but it's perfectly fine if someone knows how to do it in python (or some other programming language). It doesn't matter to me.**

Okay, so I tried next.

`A` in binary is: `01000001`

`´` in binary is: `10110100`

It together takes 15 bits, so I need UTF-8 3 bytes format (`1110xxxx  10xxxxxx  10xxxxxx`)

By filling the bits from `A` and `´` (first A) in the places of x, the following is obtained: `11100100  10000110  10110100`.

Then I converted the resulting three bytes back into hexadecimal values: `E4 86 B4`.

However, when I tried to write it in code, I got a completely different character. In other words, my solution is not working as I expected.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    r := "\xE4\x86\xB4"

    fmt.Println(r) // It wrote 䆴 instead of Á
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `´` (U+00B4) character you provided is not actually a [combining character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_Diacritical_Marks) as Unicode defines it.

```
>>> "A\u00b4"
'A´'
```

If we use `◌́` (U+0301) instead, then we can just place it in sequence with a character like `A` and get the expected output:

```
>>> "A\u0301"
'Á'
```

Unless I'm misunderstanding what you mean, it doesn't look like any binary manipulation or trickery is necessary here.

Comment: Thank you! Well, I made it more complicated than it really is.

Answer (score 0):

As StardustGogeta explains in their answer, the correct combining unicode character for an "acute" accent is U+0301 (Combining Acute Accent).

But in Go, a string consisting of the single U+00C1 (Latin Capital Letter A with Acute) character is not equal to a string consisting of a U+0041 (Latin Capital Letter A) followed by a U+0301 (Combining Acute Accent)

If you want to compare strings, you need to normalise both to the same normalisation form. See blog post [Text normalization in Go](https://go.dev/blog/normalization) for more details.

[The following code snippet](https://go.dev/play/p/NOcTMYlOPLD) shows how to do that:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "golang.org/x/text/unicode/norm"
)

func main() {
    combined := "\u00c1"
    combining := "A\u0301"
    fmt.Printf("combined = %s, combining = %s\n", combined, combining)
    fmt.Printf("combined == combining: %t\n", combined == combining)
    combiningNormalised := string(norm.NFC.Bytes([]byte(combining)))
    fmt.Printf("combined == combiningNormalised: %t\n", combined == combiningNormalised)
}
```

Output:

```
combined = Á, combining = Á
combined == combining: false
combined == combiningNormalised: true
```